# How to include Pivottable report filter header in excel vba

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I tried to generate the code to create the pivotttable report filter header with reference from recording macro. After that i tried to run it with vba to create the pivotttable report filter header based on my data but it just doesn't shows up. How to solve this issue or what other ways can i include Pivottable header when creating pivottable using VBA?

```
Dim LastRow As Long, PRange As Range
LastRow = Worksheets("Result").Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

Set PRange = Worksheets("Result").Range("A2:D" & LastRow).CurrentRegion
Dim pc As PivotCache, pt As PivotTable

Set pc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Set pt = pc.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=Worksheets("wafermapvbd1").Cells(3, 1), TableName:="PivotTable100")

Worksheets("wafermapvbd1").PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("Device_name"). _
        ClearAllFilters
    Worksheets("wafermapvbd1").PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("Device_name").CurrentPage _
        = "(All)"
   Worksheets("wafermapvbd1").PivotTables("PivotTable100").PivotFields("Device_name"). _
        EnableMultiplePageItems = True
```

**Other additional info**

**my data in worksheets("Result")**

[image]

**Actual**
[image]

**expected**
[image]

Comment: watch this video from 17th Min https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=agQAda7HphQ